# How does contributing to UN bodies allow a country to yield more influence over them?

Tags: united-states, united-nations

> For several decades, many U.S. policymakers, including some Members of
> Congress, have maintained that the U.S. assessments for the U.N.
> regular budget and U.N. peacekeeping operations are too high. In
> particular, some contend that current assessment levels for the
> regular budget result in a limited number of countries, particularly
> the United States, providing the bulk of funding while having what
> they view as minimal influence in the U.N. budget process. Some
> policymakers have expressed similar concerns about the U.S.
> peacekeeping assessment, which Congress has capped at 25%. They
> maintain that a cap on U.S. assessments plays an important role in
> keeping the current U.S. assessments from rising. **On the other hand,
> some argue that the current assessment levels allow the United States
> to share peacekeeping, development, and humanitarian funding with
> other governments (often referred to as burden sharing) at a lower
> cost than if it were to act unilaterally.40 More broadly, they contend
> that current assessment levels reflect the U.S. commitment to the
> United Nations and allow the United States to pursue its policy
> priorities and maintain its influence in U.N. bodies. Some suggest
> that if the United States were to decrease its contributions to the
> United Nations, other countries with priorities at odds with the
> United States could step in and undermine U.S. interests.**

https://sgp.fas.org/crs/row/R45206.pdf

The article seems to suggest that U.S. funding allows it to have some influence in U.N. bodies, but they argue it does without explaining through what process it achieves yielding more influence over them (ability to elect the board members, ability to veto, etc.), so how does contributing to U.N. bodies allow a country to yield more influence over them?

Comment: 1. Seems to be arguing the point in the negative sense. That US attempts to impose requirements on the UN by threatening to withhold funding, would result in reducing US influence

Comment: 2. (this is not in the linked article) there is a possibility to horse-trade, i.e. in exchange for US approving UN funding, which is of interest to country X, then when country X will reciprocate when they or their personnel are in a position to support a US-favored director of a UN body or some such position. In general that's what "influence over an organization" is about -- getting your people into key places